# search result from the looping in the same for-each loop

Tags: loops, xslt

I'm using XSLT 1.0. When looping in the address node, I need to read the current node and retrieve the data from the next node. Is it possible to do this with the code i use or do I need to do a loop within a loop? Kindly advice. Many thanks.

The code that I'm using is:

```
<Data>
 <xsl:for-each select="Record/Address>
 <xsl:if test="Objtyp='H'">
 <xsl:variable name="objkeyH" select="Objkey"/>
  <Location>
    <Region><xsl:value-of select="description"/></Region>
    <houseNumber><xsl:value-of select="houseNumber[parentID=$objkeyH]"/></houseNumber>
    <Street><xsl:value-of select="Street[parentID=$objkeyH]"/></Street>
    <Postcode><xsl:value-of select="Postcode[parentID=$objkeyH]"/></Postcode>
    <City><xsl:value-of select="City[parentID=$objkeyH]"/></City>     
  </Location>
 <xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
</Data>
```

Input:

```
<Record>
 <Address>
  <Objtyp>H</Objtyp>
  <Objkey>111</Objkey>
  <description>Santa Barbara</description>
 </Address>
 <Address>
   <Objtyp>H</Objtyp>
  <Objkey>112</Objkey>
  <description>San Diego</description>
 </Address>
 <Address>
  <Objtyp>D</Objtyp>
   <parentID>112</parentID>
   <houseNumber>11A</houseNumber>
   <Street>Avenida Del Mundo</Street>
   <Postcode>92118</Postcode>
  <City>Coronado</City>
 </Address>
</Record>
```

The output I want is as below:

```
<Data>  
 <Location>
  <Region>Santa Barbara<Region>
 </Location>
 <Location>
  <Region>San Diego<Region>
  <houseNumber>11A</houseNumber>
  <Street>Avenida Del Mundo</Street>
  <Postcode>92118</Postcode>
  <City>Coronado</City>
 </Location>
</Data>
```

Comment: It depends on whether a type H parent can have multiple type D (or other types) children. And what do you want to do with these, if they exist.

Comment: There will only have one type D and it will always be after a type H. If there is no type D after the type H then just output the type H result in the <location>. If there is a type D after a type H, then output both the result in the <location>. Type D can also be linked to type H via the field D-parentID which is type H-Objkey

Comment: Then what exactly is the problem here? Your code works (or rather would work if you fix the typos). IMHO. it would be more efficient to use a **key** to get the child data, since that is clearly what the XML author intended - but it's not essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it might be better to start off with a template based approach. Then you would have a template matching the **Address** records with an **Objtype='H'**

```
<xsl:template match="Address[Objtyp='H']">
   <Location>
      ....
```

You would also need a template to match other **Address** records, to ignore them. Such a template will have lower priority than the more specific one above

```
<xsl:template match="Address" />
```

In terms of retrieving data from another node, a key is often a better approach, so in your case you would define a key to look up **Address** records by their **parentID** value.

```
<xsl:key name="child" match="Address" use="parentID" />
```

You can then retrieve the other values like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', Objkey)/houseNumber" />
```

This has the advantage too that if **houseNumber** does not exist in the related record, nothing will be output (as opposed to an empty **houseNumber** element being output).

Finally, to rename the root **Record** node to **Data**, you would have a template for this too

```
  <xsl:template match="Record">
    <Data>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Data>
  </xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="child" match="Address" use="parentID" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Record">
    <Data>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Data>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Address[Objtyp='H']">
    <Location>
      <Region><xsl:value-of select="description"/></Region>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', Objkey)/houseNumber" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', Objkey)/Street" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', Objkey)/Postcode" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', Objkey)/City" />
    </Location>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Address" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of the [Identity Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to copy existing nodes.

Comment: Many thanks Tim for your detailed feedback. Your method works well. However by using the templete match, it copied the Input structure. I'm trying to change that but I can't change the Input structure to <Data> structure. Could you advice on how I can change to the correct <Data> structure?

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry, I missed the fact that Record is changed to Data. But this is still straight-forward with the template approach. I have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I see. I was trying to change the Record to Data at <xsl:template match="@*|node()">. Thanks again Tim for your help.